# Running Stored Procedure in HangFire

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in Hangfire. Below is the code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("UpdateActivityStatus")]
    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
    public IActionResult UpdateStatus()
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() =>
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.UpdateStatus")
        );

        return Ok();
    }
```

But I'm getting the below exception in the dashboard.

`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context`

I can understand that the database context is not being passed there. But I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: have hangfire resolve the context when invoking the job.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Nkosi. Do you have any example  code?

Comment: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html

Comment: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html

Answer (score 2):

Review the following references from documentation

Reference [Using IoC containers](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html)

Reference [Passing dependencies](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html)

and once configured you will be able to use the `Enqueue` overload that will allow for the context to be resolved when the job is invoked.

For example

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("UpdateActivityStatus")]
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
public IActionResult UpdateStatus() {
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue<MyDbContext>(context =>
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.UpdateStatus")
    );
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nkosi. Do you have any example?